# How to convert task-clock perf-event to seconds or milliseconds?

Tags: perf

I am trying to use perf for performance analysis.

When I use ***perf stat*** it provides execution time

```
Performance counter stats for './quicksort_ver1 input.txt 10000':

              7.00 msec task-clock:u              #    0.918 CPUs utilized          
         2,679,253      cycles:u                  #    0.383 GHz                      (9.58%)
        18,034,446      instructions:u            #    6.73  insn per cycle           (23.56%)
         5,764,095      branches:u                #  822.955 M/sec                    (37.62%)
         5,030,025      dTLB-loads                #  718.150 M/sec                    (51.69%)
         2,948,787      dTLB-stores               #  421.006 M/sec                    (65.75%)
         5,525,534      L1-dcache-loads           #  788.895 M/sec                    (48.31%)
         2,653,434      L1-dcache-stores          #  378.838 M/sec                    (34.25%)
             4,900      L1-dcache-load-misses     #    0.09% of all L1-dcache hits    (20.16%)
                66      LLC-load-misses           #    0.00% of all LL-cache hits     (6.09%)
     <not counted>      LLC-store-misses                                              (0.00%)
     <not counted>      LLC-loads                                                     (0.00%)
     <not counted>      LLC-stores                                                    (0.00%)

       0.007631774 seconds time elapsed

       0.006655000 seconds user
       0.000950000 seconds sys
```

However when I use ***perf record***, I observe that for task-clock 45 samples and 14999985 events are collected.

```
Samples: 45  of event 'task-clock:u', Event count (approx.): 14999985
  Children      Self  Command         Shared Object   Symbol
+   91.11%     0.00%  quicksort_ver1  quicksort_ver1  [.] _start
+   91.11%     0.00%  quicksort_ver1  libc-2.17.so    [.] __libc_start_main
+   91.11%     0.00%  quicksort_ver1  quicksort_ver1  [.] main
```

is there any way to convert task-clock events to seconds to milliseconds?

Answer (score 1):

Got answer with little bit of experimentation. Basic unit of task-cpu event is Nano second

stats collected with perf stat

```
$ sudo perf stat -e task-clock:u ./bubble_sort input.txt 50000

 Performance counter stats for './bubble_sort input.txt 50000':

         11,617.33 msec task-clock:u              #    1.000 CPUs utilized          

      11.617480215 seconds time elapsed

      11.615856000 seconds user
       0.002000000 seconds sys
```

stats collected with perf record

```
$ sudo perf report  
Samples: 35K of event 'task-clock:u', Event count (approx.): 11715321618
Overhead  Command      Shared Object  Symbol
  73.75%  bubble_sort  bubble_sort    [.] bubbleSort
  26.15%  bubble_sort  bubble_sort    [.] swap
   0.07%  bubble_sort  libc-2.17.so   [.] _IO_vfscanf


observe in both the cases sample has changed but event count is approximately same.
```

***perf stat*** reports elapsed time as 11.617480215 seconds and ***perf report*** reports total task-clock events: 11715321618

11715321618 nanoseconds = 11.715321618 seconds which is approximately equals to 11.615856000 seconds

apparently basic unit of task-cpu event is Nanosecond.